# Utilising the error layout in a hosted Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, cloud-foundry

I've just finished creating my custom error messages in my Nuxt.js application in `layouts/error.vue`. For the moment I've made it pretty simple as it's just a brochure site for the time being, so I am just handling the errors as shown below as for now I only care about users hitting a page that doesn't exist.

```
<template v-if="error.statusCode === 404">
    <h1>Sorry!</h1>
    <p>We can't find the page you are looking for.</p>
</template>
<template v-else>
    // Some other message
</template>
```

When running my application locally, and trying to navigate to a route that doesn't exist, this works perfectly and my error message is displayed.

[image]

However, my hosted application does not behave how I want it to. I'm hosting the application on IBM Cloud as a Cloud Foundry application. The application uses the static buildpack, and my `manifest.yml` file looks like so:

```
---
applications:
  - name: name
    path: ./dist
    buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git
    random-route: true
```

But if I try and navigate to an incorrect route that way, I am displayed the generic nginx 404 error:

[image]

I understand that there are 2 ways you can tell Cloud Foundry that the application requires a static buildpack - Declaring the buildpack in the `manifest.yml` OR adding a file named `Staticfile` in the `dist` directory after running `npm run generate`. Within this file, you can add some configurations, one of which being status codes which:

> Allows to define custom pages for HTTP STATUS codes instead of the default NGINX pages.

```
status_codes:
  404: /404.html
  500: /500.html
```

However, my error handling is done in a layout, not a page. And my generated project folder does not contain a page called error anywhere, so I don't know how to use this method to use my error handling.

If anybody could give me some pointers on how to correctly do it, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try adding `pushstate: enabled` into your Staticfile? That will basically route any requests which do not map to actual files on disk to your main app page. That would then typically get routed by Vue (or whatever JS framework you use).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @DanielMikusa. I just tried adding that to my Staticfile, and it no longer routes me to the default nginx page if I hit a bad link. However, its throwing the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.`

Comment: I'm not sure about that error, but I think it is closer to what you want because it's failing in the browser. I don't think you want Nginx handling the error page because you're trying to handle it in the browser in your Vue.js code. Double-check your Vue.js code & browser debugger for more clues. If you get stuck, if you can post or link to a demo to repro the problem I can take a closer look.